# Is the measure of a random variable Lebesgue or Borel?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

A random variable is a map from the sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R,$ but things get more complicated because only in discrete random variables can the cardinality measure be used to calculate probabilities. This leads to the construction of sigma algebras $\mathcal F$ with collections of sets that are measurable, and a mapping from these measurable sets in $\mathcal F$ to Borel sets in the real line or the measurable space $(\mathbb R, \mathcal O).$ A probability law induced by the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ on the real line would allow these Borel sets, and very specifically, semi-infinite intervals $(-\infty, a]$ to be mapped to a measure given by the CDF.

My question is whether this measure is a Lebesgue or Borel measure or a Borel-Stieltjes measure (and what are the differences), to complete the triad on the range of the random variable as, for instance $(\mathbb R, \mathcal O, \lambda),$ where $\lambda$ would represent the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: what measure? the measure in the probability space or the measure induced in $\Bbb R$ by a random variable? The latter is Borel in the sense that its defined in the Borel sigma algebra, and the first cannot be categorized Borel or Lebegue because we will need a topology for $\Omega$ what is generally unknown or unimportant

Comment: @Masacroso The latter. I have seen this $(\mathbb R, \mathcal O, \lambda).$